# Convergence of infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, products

This could be something which is already somewhere in the website, but I am unable to locate any.

Prove $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z^n)$$ converges absolutely and uniformly on each compact subset of $\biggr[{|z|<1}\biggr]$.

What about $\biggr[{|z|>1}\biggr]$?

I have a feeling this need to be done with using some logarithm expansion and using Weierstrass theorem. But I do like to see more ideas of proof. I am not sure on using those ideas either.

Comment: Try taking $z=1+\epsilon$.  What happens to the size of the terms in the product?

Comment: For more references see ['Euler function'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the definition of absolute convergence of a product: $\prod(1+y_n)$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum|y_n|$ converges. You can also use the fact that a necessary condition for a product $\prod(1+y_n)$ to converge is that $y_n\to0$. These two statements should allow you to prove the first statement and show that in the second case, the product diverges.

Comment: So the hint given by @Eric Naslund make sense now. Thanks Greg Martin.

Comment: You're welcome! This is a good example to show why the fundamentals of a subject are so important. We can't treat every problem like a brand new mystery unto itself; we need to build up basic techniques to run new problems by, to sort the easily solved ones from the ones that require deeper though.